# Create separate thread Pools for a pool of Platform Threads in java

Tags: java, threadpoolexecutor, java-threads, java-21, virtual-threads

I want to create pool of virtual threads running on separate pool of Java Threads.

Here's the architecture I am trying to create:

[image: architecture]

This is to enable me to create separate pools to run batch tasks in one JVM and take benefit of virtual threads with n:m mapping for each pool. So if i have 12 cores then i can create 2 ThreadPools of 6 Threads. Each pool will only execute a specific task. Each pool will have N number of VirtualThreads. So, here the mapping would be 2 pools of {N VirtualThreads -> 6 Platform Threads}.

TLDR, I want to limit the number of PlatformThreads that a pool of virtual threads can run on.

One thing i could think of is, create the thread pool and when passing in a runnable, inside the run method I could just create virtual threads but the not sure how practical is it and will i be getting the pool partition that i want. Another issue with this approach is, the virtual threads will be running in just one java thread, so no N:M mapping

Comment: What is the issue you have when creating thread pools? You can even specify a ` ThreadFactory`, which will create virtual threads for you. Please [edit] your question to include a more detailed description. Also add the source code you have already tried and what the problem is with the source code you have.

Comment: @Progman Yeah, I Could create a ThreadFactory as pass it in but still i wont be able to limit the number of platform threads the pool can run on.

Comment: [Never pool virtual threads.](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/21/core/virtual-threads.html#GUID-C0FEE349-D998-4C9D-B032-E01D06BE55F2)

Comment: @VGR I did read that, but in my case with what i want to create does make sense. My use case uses job dependent on each other (basically output of one job provides input to another in queue). I want to be able to create a ThreadPool for each job and each task in the job will be a Vthread. The jobs don't take equal amount of time per task so I should be able to provide some allocation to each job based on its requirements. This will enable me to stream jobs into one another. Now each job may use Vthread or Pthread based on the operation (I/O or compute).

Comment: Virtual threads are not designed to be reused.  Keeping a pool of them undermines how they work.  Your job should just create the virtual threads it needs as it needs them, and should not attempt to pool them.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "so I should be able to provide some allocation to each job based on its requirements"?

Comment: I suggest you revamp your Question to explain your need and your requirement,. What prompted you to devise this pooling solution? This looks like an [XY problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XY_problem).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[Virtual threads](https://openjdk.org/jeps/444) were invented to avoid the bother you seem to be undertaking.

And, virtual threads are explicitly documented as *not* being intended for pooling. Like [facial tissues](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Facial_tissue), grab a fresh one, use it, and dispose.

Read the Java JEP, and watch videos with Ron Pressler, Alan Bateman, José Paumard, etc. to understand the purpose and nature of virtual thread technology.

You said:

> My use case uses job dependent on each other (basically output of one job provides input to another in queue).

… and:

> when passing in a runnable, inside the run method I could just create virtual threads

Turn your thinking inside-out: Instead of creating virtual threads to run a bunch of related cascading tasks, create just one thread to do all the work in serial fashion.

If you have a series of cascading tasks, each task picking up after the previous task‘s result, then simply write wrap all that work in a single `Runnable`/`Callable`. Execute that single combined task in a single new fresh virtual thread. Let that virtual thread run to completion.

Let's devise a simple demo app. We have three tasks that feed into one another, `TaskA`, `TaskB`, and `TaskC`. They are housed together as `AlphabetTask`. The result is "ABC", each letter having been added by each subtask.

```java
class AlphabetTask implements Callable < String >
{
    private final UUID id = UUID.randomUUID ( );

    @Override
    public String call ( ) throws Exception
    {
        System.out.println ( "Starting AlphabetTask " + this.id + " " + Instant.now ( ) );
        String a = new TaskA ( ).call ( );
        String b = new TaskB ( a ).call ( );
        String c = new TaskC ( b ).call ( );
        System.out.println ( "Ending AlphabetTask " + this.id + " Result: " + c + " " + Instant.now ( ) );
        return c;
    }
}

class TaskA implements Callable < String >
{
    @Override
    public String call ( ) throws Exception
    {
        System.out.println ( "Running TaskA. " + Instant.now ( ) );
        Thread.sleep ( Duration.ofMillis ( ThreadLocalRandom.current ( ).nextInt ( 100 , 800 ) ) );
        return "A";
    }
}

class TaskB implements Callable < String >
{
    private final String input;

    public TaskB ( final String input )
    {
        this.input = input;
    }

    @Override
    public String call ( ) throws Exception
    {
        System.out.println ( "Running TaskB. " + Instant.now ( ) );
        Thread.sleep ( Duration.ofMillis ( ThreadLocalRandom.current ( ).nextInt ( 100 , 800 ) ) );
        return this.input + "B";
    }
}

class TaskC implements Callable < String >
{
    private final String input;

    public TaskC ( final String input )
    {
        this.input = input;
    }

    @Override
    public String call ( ) throws Exception
    {
        System.out.println ( "Running TaskC. " + Instant.now ( ) );
        Thread.sleep ( Duration.ofMillis ( ThreadLocalRandom.current ( ).nextInt ( 100 , 800 ) ) );
        return this.input + "C";
    }
}
```

We establish three instances of *AlphabetTask*.

```java
Collection < AlphabetTask > alphabetTasks =
        List.of (
                new AlphabetTask ( ) ,
                new AlphabetTask ( ) ,
                new AlphabetTask ( )
        );
```

We submit all of those instances to an executor service. For each of those three `AlphabetTasks`, the executor assigns a fresh new virtual thread. Within each virtual thread, each of our subtasks are called in sequential order.

Notice that we can use try-with-resources syntax to automatically close our executor service if its tasks complete in under a day.

```java
List < Future < String > > futures = List.of ( );
try (
        ExecutorService executorService = Executors.newVirtualThreadPerTaskExecutor ( ) ;
)
{
    try
    {
        futures = executorService.invokeAll ( alphabetTasks );
    } catch ( InterruptedException e )
    {
        throw new RuntimeException ( e );
    }
}
// The try-with-resources blocks here if executor service has any uncompleted tasks.
futures.forEach ( stringFuture -> {
    try
    {
        System.out.println ( stringFuture.get ( ) );
    } catch ( InterruptedException | ExecutionException e )
    {
        throw new RuntimeException ( e );
    }
} );
```

Caveat: Virtual threads are appropriate to tasks where the code involves blocking, such as file I/O, network I/O, database calls, waiting on a lock, etc. Do *not* use virtual threads to run CPU-bound tasks such as video encoding (no blocking involved).

When run:

```
Starting AlphabetTask 3a594ed1-a76e-4927-83b1-2d6bc81f566c 2023-12-03T20:30:03.442091Z
Starting AlphabetTask 12743216-8e42-4be1-bfc4-1893e08e58a7 2023-12-03T20:30:03.442091Z
Starting AlphabetTask 94a4d5b9-3ed9-43d4-ba66-509380fa9f8b 2023-12-03T20:30:03.442091Z
Running TaskA. 2023-12-03T20:30:03.452388Z
Running TaskA. 2023-12-03T20:30:03.452392Z
Running TaskA. 2023-12-03T20:30:03.452383Z
Running TaskB. 2023-12-03T20:30:03.556780Z
Running TaskB. 2023-12-03T20:30:03.687342Z
Running TaskC. 2023-12-03T20:30:03.812744Z
Running TaskB. 2023-12-03T20:30:04.108820Z
Running TaskC. 2023-12-03T20:30:04.278596Z
Ending AlphabetTask 94a4d5b9-3ed9-43d4-ba66-509380fa9f8b Result: ABC 2023-12-03T20:30:04.310085Z
Running TaskC. 2023-12-03T20:30:04.360861Z
Ending AlphabetTask 3a594ed1-a76e-4927-83b1-2d6bc81f566c Result: ABC 2023-12-03T20:30:04.624803Z
Ending AlphabetTask 12743216-8e42-4be1-bfc4-1893e08e58a7 Result: ABC 2023-12-03T20:30:04.953132Z
ABC
ABC
ABC
```

Beware: Output on console may *not* appear in chronological order when calling `System.out.println` across threads. Include and inspect timestamps if you care about order.

---

Here is all of that code for your copy-paste convenience, to be dropped into a single `.java` file.

```java
package work.basil.example.threading;

import java.time.Duration;
import java.time.Instant;
import java.util.Collection;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.UUID;
import java.util.concurrent.*;

public class Subtasks
{
    public static void main ( String[] args )
    {
        Subtasks app = new Subtasks ( );
        app.demo ( );
    }

    private void demo ( )
    {
        Collection < AlphabetTask > alphabetTasks =
                List.of (
                        new AlphabetTask ( ) ,
                        new AlphabetTask ( ) ,
                        new AlphabetTask ( )
                );
        List < Future < String > > futures = List.of ( );
        try (
                ExecutorService executorService = Executors.newVirtualThreadPerTaskExecutor ( ) ;
        )
        {
            try
            {
                futures = executorService.invokeAll ( alphabetTasks );
            } catch ( InterruptedException e )
            {
                throw new RuntimeException ( e );
            }
        }
        // The try-with-resources blocks here if executor service has any uncompleted tasks.
        futures.forEach ( stringFuture -> {
            try
            {
                System.out.println ( stringFuture.get ( ) );
            } catch ( InterruptedException | ExecutionException e )
            {
                throw new RuntimeException ( e );
            }
        } );
    }
}

class AlphabetTask implements Callable < String >
{
    private final UUID id = UUID.randomUUID ( );

    @Override
    public String call ( ) throws Exception
    {
        System.out.println ( "Starting AlphabetTask " + this.id + " " + Instant.now ( ) );
        String a = new TaskA ( ).call ( );
        String b = new TaskB ( a ).call ( );
        String c = new TaskC ( b ).call ( );
        System.out.println ( "Ending AlphabetTask " + this.id + " Result: " + c + " " + Instant.now ( ) );
        return c;
    }
}

class TaskA implements Callable < String >
{
    @Override
    public String call ( ) throws Exception
    {
        System.out.println ( "Running TaskA. " + Instant.now ( ) );
        Thread.sleep ( Duration.ofMillis ( ThreadLocalRandom.current ( ).nextInt ( 100 , 800 ) ) );
        return "A";
    }
}

class TaskB implements Callable < String >
{
    private final String input;

    public TaskB ( final String input )
    {
        this.input = input;
    }

    @Override
    public String call ( ) throws Exception
    {
        System.out.println ( "Running TaskB. " + Instant.now ( ) );
        Thread.sleep ( Duration.ofMillis ( ThreadLocalRandom.current ( ).nextInt ( 100 , 800 ) ) );
        return this.input + "B";
    }
}

class TaskC implements Callable < String >
{
    private final String input;

    public TaskC ( final String input )
    {
        this.input = input;
    }

    @Override
    public String call ( ) throws Exception
    {
        System.out.println ( "Running TaskC. " + Instant.now ( ) );
        Thread.sleep ( Duration.ofMillis ( ThreadLocalRandom.current ( ).nextInt ( 100 , 800 ) ) );
        return this.input + "C";
    }
}
```

You said:

> So if i have 12 cores then i can create 2 ThreadPools of 6 Threads.

You do not have as much control as you seem to believe. Which platform-threads run on which core at which time for what duration is all up to the host OS. And the scheduling behavior varies moment by moment depending on the current loads on the computer. At any moment, none, few, or all of your threads may be executing.

Comment: I think your methodology make 10x more sense. Instead of running each type of task on separate pools, packing all the tasks into one serial code per unit makes more sense. This way i can easily get the benefit of virtualThreads whenever a I/O operation occurs. Time to go on with my project to create a library based on this case on maven.

Comment: @Holger I was trying to make clear how the try-with-resources works with an `AutoCloseable` executor service. I rewrote the text to be more general. Thank you for your Comment.

Answer (score 3):

You're approaching this wrong.

What you really seem to want to do is *limit the concurrency* of certain kinds of tasks.  That is, you want at most M1 of the first kind of task (call them A-tasks) to be able to run concurrently, and at most M2 of the second kind of task (call them B-tasks) to be able to run concurrently.  But trying to create pools of virtual threads bound to pools of platform threads is solving this problem at the wrong level.

If you want to limit the concurrency of a given activity, the proper tool for this is a semaphore.  Create a semaphore for each kind of task, A and B.  A-tasks require a permit from the A semaphore; B tasks require a permit from the B semaphore.  It is trivial to wrap a task with acquire-release of a semaphore, so you can do this as part of the submission logic rather than the task business logic if you like.  Each task runs in a virtual thread.

You might think: "but then I might have a lot of virtual threads waiting for the A semaphore."  Yes, you might.  But you don't care; they are cheap.  Create one per task, and don't try to pool them.  (It also means you don't need separate pools of platform threads.)

Comment: This assumes that all tasks are equally important which in my experience is almost never the case. A major reason to create multiple thread pools is to set the thread priority to different values so that batch tasks yield to interactive tasks. This issue is common with the shared ForkJoin pool but is easy to remedy with a custom ForkJoinExecutor. I am yet to find similar solution with Virtual Threads.